# Wowza Live stream video not stored in 'content' folder

Tags: android, video-streaming, live-streaming, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I am using Wowza Live streaming functionality in my android application. I have downloaded the sample demo from below link:

https://github.com/WowzaMediaSystems/gocoder-sdk-samples-android

I am executing the sample demo after installing Wowza Stream Engine in my mac.

The demo is working fine, I am able to connect and disconnect. The issue is with storing functionality.

I come to know that:

**If you're recording the stream it will be stored in the content directory allocated to the application. The default storage directory is the [Wowza-Install]/content/directory.**

But, After Live Stream disconnects, I am not finding any video stored in my content directory.

What might be issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers

Comment: Did you explicitly record the stream (via Incoming Streams page) or set the application to record all incoming streams?

Comment: Sir, I installed Wowza Stream Engine and using IP for the live streaming. Found the github demo from here : https://github.com/WowzaMediaSystems/gocoder-sdk-samples-android. There is option to record live stream, I have not done anything more in that demo. I have to do anything to record live stream so that that appers in CONTENT folder ?

Comment: To auto-record, access the live app (e.g. */Home.htm#application/_defaultVHost_/live/live/main), click Edit, and check the "Record all incoming streams" checkbox.  To arbitrarily record a live, active stream, click on Live > Incoming Streams and click the red record button.